# How to make the Code for this question optimized?

Tags: c++

The city of Darkishland has a strange hotel with infinite rooms. The groups that come to this hotel follow the following rules:

At the same time only members of one group can rent the hotel.
Each group comes in the morning of the check-in day and leaves the hotel in the evening of the check-out day.
Another group comes in the very next morning after the previous group has left the hotel.

A very important property of the incoming group is that it has one more member than its previous group unless it is the starting group. You will be given the number of members of the starting group.

A group with `n` members stays for `n` days in the hotel. For example, if a group of four members comes on August 1st in the morning, it will leave the hotel on August 4th in the evening and the next group of five members will come on August 5th in the morning and stay for five days and so on.

Given the initial group size you will have to find the group size staying in the hotel on a specified day.

**Input**

`S` denotes the initial size of the group and `D` denotes that you will have to find the group size staying in the hotel on `D-th` day (starting from 1). A group size `S` means that on the first day a group of `S` members comes to the hotel and stays for `S` days. Then comes a group of `S + 1` members according to the previously described rules and so on.

---

I did this question in the following way

```cpp
long long groupSize(long long S, long long D) {
    for(; (D-S) > 0; S++) {
        D = D - S;
    }
    return S;
}
```

But the question said I should optimize it.

How can I make my answer optimal?

Comment: You'll have to optimize it by using math.

Comment: Attack this algorithmically, as in using a mathematical function, *not* by brute-forcing it.

Comment: When you have a problem that has the general statement of `x` things happening `y` times with a few constants thrown in, and where `x` or `y` are increasing/decreasing by a fixed amount, that is a mathematics problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the for loop goes for n steps, it means that:
D > S + (S+1) + ... + (S+n-1)

You can solve this issue analytically and apply correction to the potential numerical error.

```
long long groupSize(long long S, long long D)
{
    long long twoSMinus1 = 2 * S - 1;
    // solution of quadratic equation
    long long result1 = 0.5 * (sqrt(8 * D +  twoSMinus1 * twoSMinus1) - twoSMinus1);
    long long result2 = result1 - 1;
    
    // You have to make sure that numerical error did not mess up the result
    if (result1 * (result1- 1) / 2 + result1 * S < D)
    {
        return result1 + S;
    }

    return result2 + S;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(S; (D-S)> 0;S++){
  D= D-S;
}
```

Running the loop is not optimal; rather, you can directly compute the answer in a fixed number of operations.

If this is a question for a Discrete Math class, the techniques should be what you were studying.  `D_next = D - S` is a *recurrence relation*.

You keep incrementing S, so you subtract 1, then 2, then 3, etc.  There is a simple formula for the sum of 1..n.  Solve for n when that sum equals (original) D.